Wix installer failed to execute exe package doing quiet install
I am trying to perform a quiet install of an exe file from FTDI drivers. I am getting these drivers from here. After downloading, when I 7-zip further extract the .exe, it creates a folder with dlls and dpinst-amd64.exe just as in the screenshot below. When I try the command

dpinst-amd64.exe /q /se

On command prompt, it works fine. But doing so with Wix installer is failing to run the package. However the other packages install fine within this code.

This is what I have in the Bundle.wxs
<Chain>

      <ExePackage Id="FTDIDriversInstaller"
                  SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\FTDIDrivers_Setup\dpinst-amd64.exe"
                  InstallCommand="/s /se"
                  Compressed="yes"/>
            <!--VC++ Redistributable required to ensure the ADE installer executes without errors-->
            <ExePackage Id="VCRedistributableInstaller"
                        SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\VC_redist.x64.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart"
                        Compressed="yes" />
<ExePackage Id="VCRedistributable2010Installer"
                        SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\VCREDIST_2010_x64.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/quiet /norestart"
                        Compressed="yes" />
            <MsiPackage Id="LicenseGeneratorInstaller"
                        SourceFile="$(var.ReleaseFolder)\!(loc.CULTURE)\FactoryToolsInstall.msi"
                        Compressed="yes"
                        DisplayInternalUI="yes" />
            <ExePackage Id="AccessDatabaseEngineInstaller"
                        SourceFile="$(var.DependencyFolder)\AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe"
                        InstallCommand="/quiet"
                        Compressed="yes" />
                                
        </Chain>

This is what I see in the log file:

[1740:173C][2024-11-29T12:25:25]i305: Verified acquired payload: FTDIDriversInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache.unverified\FTDIDriversInstaller, moving to: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\A6D6831A4A097BD47AF267727A4AD6B38B14CDE3\dpinst-amd64.exe.
[1740:173C][2024-11-29T12:25:26]i304: Verified existing payload: VCRedistributableInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\BA92A00F0F55DCAE85C1BBD098EFE606BD080B3C\VC_redist.x64.exe.
[1740:173C][2024-11-29T12:25:26]i304: Verified existing payload: VCRedistributable2010Installer at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\027D0C2749EC5EB21B031F46AEE14C905206F482\VCREDIST_2010_x64.exe.
[1740:173C][2024-11-29T12:25:29]i304: Verified existing payload: SQL2017Express at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\E0A5A388255244F1F5EB2FBF46BDC7292F7E3D8E\Redist\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe.
[1740:173C][2024-11-29T12:25:30]i304: Verified existing payload: PharmSpecInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{04E45023-61F9-47AB-8E79-D9A2FE234FC8}v3.5.33\PharmSpec.msi.
[1740:173C][2024-11-29T12:25:33]i304: Verified existing payload: AccessDatabaseEngineInstaller at path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\277EA5EBCD18B8B98D82C9DC53399B4FE864CA51\AccessDatabaseEngine_X64.exe.
[1740:1748][2024-11-29T12:25:33]i301: Applying execute package: FTDIDriversInstaller, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\A6D6831A4A097BD47AF267727A4AD6B38B14CDE3\dpinst-amd64.exe, arguments: '"C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\A6D6831A4A097BD47AF267727A4AD6B38B14CDE3\dpinst-amd64.exe" /q /se'
[1740:1748][2024-11-29T12:25:33]e000: Error 0x80000000: Process returned error: 0x80000000
[1740:1748][2024-11-29T12:25:33]e000: Error 0x80000000: Failed to execute EXE package.
[0F88:1444][2024-11-29T12:25:33]e000: Error 0x80000000: Failed to configure per-machine EXE package.
[0F88:1444][2024-11-29T12:25:33]i319: Applied execute package: FTDIDriversInstaller, result: 0x80000000, restart: None
[0F88:1444][2024-11-29T12:25:33]e000: Error 0x80000000: Failed to execute EXE package.
[1740:1748][2024-11-29T12:25:33]i351: Removing cached package: FTDIDriversInstaller, from path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\A6D6831A4A097BD47AF267727A4AD6B38B14CDE3\


The following may be of interest: https://serverfault.com/questions/1066805/dpinst-is-showing-the-ui-screen-even-after-sending-silent-parameters-how-to-fix

You probably need to add all those loose files as Payload elements under the dpinst ExePackage element so they are all available when the command runs.

Can you please help me with this similar question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79241426/wix-exepackage-payload-sourcefile-complains-about-having-illegal-characters
